when I run the appium test, I get an error that the address is invalid
I get this error when I run my test:
Error initializing AndroidDriver: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
This error occurs when Appium is unable to initiate a new session with the AndroidDriver, which is responsible for driving automation on Android devices or emulators. This is a critical step in starting an Appium session, and failure to do so usually stops further automation execution.
Here is my code:
package appiumbasics;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class RunWebAppAndroid {

    @Test
    public void OpenWebAppInChrome() throws MalformedURLException {
        // Step 1: Start Appium service locally
        AppiumServiceBuilder serviceBuilder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
        serviceBuilder.usingPort(4723); // Use default port 4723

        // Step 2: Start the Appium Service
        AppiumDriverLocalService service =       AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(serviceBuilder);
        service.start(); // Start the Appium service

        // Step 3: Set Desired Capabilities for Android device and Chrome
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554"); // Set emulator device name
        caps.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome"); // Set Chrome as the browser

        // Step 4: WebDriverManager to set up ChromeDriver
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        caps.setCapability("chromeExecutable", WebDriverManager.chromedriver().getBrowserPath());

        // Step 5: Initialize the AndroidDriver
        AndroidDriver driver = null;
        try {
            // Start driver with the Appium service URL and capabilities
            driver = new AndroidDriver(service.getUrl(), caps);

            // Step 6: Open the web app (replace with your URL)
            driver.get("http://example.com"); // Replace with your web app URL
            System.out.println("Web App opened successfully on Chrome browser in emulator.");

            // Step 7: You can add additional automation steps here
            // For example, interact with the web page using WebDriver methods
            // driver.findElement(...).click();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error initializing AndroidDriver: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (driver != null) {
                // Quit the driver after the test
                driver.quit();
            }
            // Stop the Appium service
            service.stop();
        }
    }
}


I am trying to run a web app on an Android emulator with Chrome as the browser. Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue?

since you've just pasted chatgpt code, try using chatgpt to debug the error as well. appium start issues are notoriously difficult to troubleshoot

I tried to see if the solution is available on chatgpt but it didn't help me.
Can you help me fix this issue?

like i said, appium launch issues are terible to debug. just take small steps, post errors to chatgpt and solve them one by one. because there is usually more then just a single error with appium. i dont believe anyone here can reliably tell you what the actuall issue is.

Thank you very much. I found another way to run the server, but I haven't solved the issue yet.
